# Support Markdown editing within rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown

I allow my users to create assignments and distribute them to their employees. Assignments have a attribute called description. Instead of users filling out a plain text field to create a description I want to give them a editable markdown supported box to fill in. exactly like the one I'm filling out now. I've never built anything like this out before, but I'm wondering if there is a Ruby gem or plugin that will help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you [SimpleMDE](https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor) javascript markdown editor. In this case you don't need a ruby gem for markdown because SimpleMDE can generate html version for you. You need to just save in your database both versions - markdown and html.

We have table `assignments` with two fields `description` to keep a markdown version and `description_html` to keep a html version of a question. As far you create common rails assignments' form and bind simplemde instance to `description` textarea. For `description_html` create hidden field tag:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :description_html %>
<%= f.textarea :description %>
```

On any change simplemde will save a html version to `description_html` hidden field:

```
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({ element: $("#MyID")[0] });
  simplemde.codemirror.on("change", function(){
  # set a html to a hidden field 
  $('#description_html_id_CHANGE_IT').val(simplemde.getHtmlValue());
});
```

Comment: Relying on javascript to generate html and "trusting" this html to be safe isn't the best idea.

Comment: @yoones wyswig editors too generates html code and their used everywhere. Of course a safe code should sanitize a html.

Comment: This looks great. One question, how exactly do I save those value in the database?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use github's gem for that: https://github.com/github/markup

First install a couple of gems:

- github/markup
- html-pipeline
- nokogiri
- nokogiri-diff

Then try the following:

```
require "github/markup"
require 'html/pipeline'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'nokogiri/diff'

filename = ARGV.first
puts GitHub::Markup.render(filename, File.read(filename)).strip.force_encoding("utf-8")
```

Comment: I'd like to use Github's but there is virtually no documentation.

Comment: @Bitwise I just added an example, you can check it out.